# Is it possible to use an IF expression to filter column choices depending on previous column?

Tags: 2010, filter, library

I am creating a site for training documents. I have 2 fields, topic and category. Is it possible to filter the options within category depending on which option the user selects in the topic column using an IF expression? Any other suggestions of how to do this are welcome, I'm just not particularly hot at coding...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out: http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/01/using-calculated-columns-to-write-html/

I'm not sure if this is the end all be all answer to this but there is a way you can write IF statements in Calculated Columns of a list. That blog has many tutorials based on Calculated Columns so you might be able to figure something out. I personally havent filtered based on that but I have added CSS.

I think another way to accomplish this is through list views? For example if you have 2 categories, Self Help and Other Help and the documents are split into these categories, you can create 2 views:

View 1: Filter by Self Help (should be an option on the edit view page)
 View 2: Filter by Other Help (should be an option on the edit view page)

*Note: If you have a lot of categories this might not be the best idea as you would have to create a lot of views...

Now when viewing the list the user can select which view to see from the top ribbon, so basically its filtering using views.

Those are just two ideas that I can think of right now...give it a try!